# Python and module - date

Tags: python, date, module

If I don't have access to the Python time module, how would I determine the number of days that have passed since I was born? That is, within the code, how many days old I am?

The code I am trying to understand better is this:
import time

```
start = raw_input(“Enter the time stamp in seconds: “)
start = float(start)

end = time.time()

elapsed = end - start

st_elapsed = time.gmtime(elapsed)

print "\n"

hours_mins_secs = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", st_elapsed)

print "Elapsed time in HH:MM:SS ->", hours_mins_secs, "\n"
```

---

Now, I looked to the site https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html
but I didn't find the alternative related to time, without using module time.

My goal is understand better this code.

Comment: If I didn't have access to the `time` module, I'd reinstall Python. Then I'd write a program that uses the `time` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a homework question. You should give us what you've done so far and we will help you. SO users are not your personal coders.
(No criticism intended)

Comment: this looks like a comment

Comment: This is one exercise from virtual lab that has the code above.